# Anagram Checking

Tags: java, optimization, strings

```
public class AnagramNumber {

    public static void checkAnagram(String[] str)
    {   
        String[] sortedArray=new String[str.length];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
        char[] strToCharArray=str[i].toCharArray();
        sortedArray[i]=new String(sortCharArray(strToCharArray));
        }

        boolean flag=true;
        for(int j=0;j<sortedArray.length-1;j++)
        {   
            if(!sortedArray[j].equals(sortedArray[j+1]))
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag)
            System.out.println("The array has anagrams");
        else
            System.out.println("The array doesnt have only anagrams");  
    }

    public static char[] sortCharArray(char[] charArray)
    {
        char temp='\u0000';
        for(int i=0;i<charArray.length-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<charArray.length;j++)
            {
                if(charArray[j]>charArray[i])
                {
                    temp=charArray[j];
                    charArray[j]=charArray[i];
                    charArray[i]=temp;
                }   

            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));
        }

        return charArray;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] str={"hello","helol","elloh"};

        checkAnagram(str);

    }
}
```

Please review program and provide the best practices and feedback on code optimizing.

Comment: please provide a bit of background. Are you trying to implement your own sorting algorithm? Otherwise, trust `Arrays.sort` from `Java`. Your sorting algorithm is using bubble sort which has O(n^2) complexity. There are faster algorithms. Also, do you have restriction in using built in methods in `String`class? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692221/anagram-algorithm-in-java)

Comment: This was an interview question in which I was asked to implement any sorting technique and not use the Arrays.sort()...no restriction on built in methods of String class

Comment: then you can probably use `toCharArray` method of `String`. Sorting of course you have to perform with your own provided method then. If they had not insisted on sorting, another way would be to build 2 maps, each with key=a unique char and val=#occurences and then check for equality. That is faster than sorting solution. Btw., this was asked for an interview to me as well few weeks ago, I proposed both solutions I mentioned and was selected (though I did not know what an Anagram was until then) :-)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 2nd solution? I didnt get it completely

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045640/how-to-check-if-two-words-are-anagrams-in-java) post, especially the selected answer.

Answer (score 7):

Besides what others have mentioned:

- `System.out.println` in your sorting method just confused me. Either inform what exactly you are logging or remove it entirely. Preferably remove it.
- Speaking of removing, your sorting method can be replaced by a call to `Arrays.sort(strToCharArray);`

  ```
  char[] strToCharArray = str[i].toCharArray();
  Arrays.sort(strToCharArray);
  sortedArray[i] = new String(strToCharArray);
  ```
- Make your `checkAnagram` method (which should be renamed to `verifyIsOnlyAnagrams` or something similar) more flexible by returning the value of `flag` instead of outputting the result.

  ```
  boolean flag = true;
  for (int j = 0; j < sortedArray.length - 1; j++) {
      ...
  }

  return flag;
  ```

  And then let the `main` method deal with the output:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] str={"hello","helol","elloh"};
      if (verifyIsOnlyAnagram(str)) {
          System.out.println(...);
      }
      else {
          System.out.println(...);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: `System.out.println` is an expansive operation most of the time, this is a really major performance problem in a many cases. +1 for removing it!

Answer (score 5):

**Indentation**

Your indentation seems consistent in your code, except for this part. It could be a problem in the question here on Code Review, but always pay attention to the indentation of your code. It's a major point for good readability.

> ```
>     for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
>     {
>     char[] strToCharArray=str[i].toCharArray();
>     sortedArray[i]=new String(sortCharArray(strToCharArray));
>     }
> ```

You should add spaces in all your conditions :

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
> ```

Should be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
```

**Brace { }**

This could be argue whether or not this is best practice, but I always like to see brackets, even if there is only one line of code. This can save a lot of troubles and if you ever need to add something to the block you won't have to add braces.

> ```
>     if(flag)
>         System.out.println("The array has anagrams");
>     else
>         System.out.println("The array doesnt have only anagrams");
> ```

One thing for sure is that the first `{` should always be at the end of the line, not on a new line.

```
public static void checkAnagram(String[] str) {

}
```

**Comments**

You should remove `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` since this is now obsolete. This serve nothing in your code.

**Naming**

There is some variables that could have a better name. Take `boolean flag`, by the name I know that it's a flag, but a flag for what ? This is not clear at all by the name. You could have use a relevant name that would show what are you flagging.

Another example :

> ```
> public static void checkAnagram(String[] str)
> ```

The name `str` is not relevant at all. I already know by the class that this is a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback....Could you also provide feedback on how i could optimize the code?

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to look deep in your algo, but if there is no other answer by the time I'm free, I will gladly do it.

Answer (score 5):

**Naming**
Your naming is quite verbose, which is good (not counting `flag`), but sometimes, although the name *looks* meaningful, it actually does not convey any useful meaning:

- `AnagramNumber` - what does this class actually do? Counts the number of anagrams? Maybe finds anagrams for a number? Someone reading your code will never guess...
- `checkAnagram` - what does it check for? Does it return anything?
- `str` - OK, this is just a generic name, but it is extra confusing, since `str` implies a single string, while you expect an array. Btw, an array of words? sentences? URLs?
- `"The array has anagrams"` vs `"The array doesnt have only anagrams"` - these sentences are *not* complementary, so one is obviously wrong. The first *should* say "The array has only anagrams". This is especially important, because you are not only talking with the reader of your code, here you are talking to your ***user***. Confusing him means you have failed your task.
- `char temp='\u0000';` - this value is never used, so making it so verbose is confusing. A better choice would be not initializing the `temp` at all (`char temp`), or, better yet, declare it only where needed (`char temp = charArray[i]`)
- `public static char[] sortCharArray(char[] charArray)` - here the problem is a little more subtle, but all the more serious. The signature of the method (returning a `char[]`) implies that it *creates a new* sorted array. Actually, it modifies the *input array itself*.
  Either create a new array, and leave the one given as it is, or remove the return value. This will make it clear that the input array changes.

**Exit Strategy**
Your use of `flag` makes your code a little awkward. Initializing it with `false`, and changing it to `true` makes it even more obfuscated, as it is counter-intuitive to most coders. As its name does not convey it any meaning, your gentle reader is left to guess its meaning by reading your code over and over...
I would drop the flag altogether, breaking from the method itself upon finding your stop condition:

```
for(int j=0;j<sortedArray.length-1;j++)
{   
    if(!sortedArray[j].equals(sortedArray[j+1]))
    {
        System.out.println("The array doesn't have only anagrams");  
        return;
    }
}

System.out.println("The array has only anagrams");
```

**Optimizations**
Since you don't give any background, it is hard to give you feedback on your algorithm - are you trying to implement a specific sorting algorithm on your own? are you simply not familiar with java's own solution to sorting (`Arrays.sort`)? Optimal solutions for sorting an array are with complexity of \$O(n \cdot log(n))\$, your solution is \$O(n^2)\$, so there is room for improvement there... you can find a myriad of sorting algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

You could further optimize your code by making a few quick checks on your data before doing the heavy lifting. For example: if not all the strings have the same *length*, you can immediately determine that they are not all an anagram of one another, and save yourself the sorting.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback....I will incorporate it from the next program i write

Comment: public static char[] sortCharArray(char[] charArray) - here the problem is a little more subtle, but all the more serious. The signature of the method (returning a char[]) implies that it creates a new sorted array. Actually, it modifies the input array itself.
Either create a new array, and leave the one given as it is, or remove the return value. This will make it clear that the input array changes......Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @user3296744 The suggestion is to either make `sortCharArray` be a `void` return method, or creating a copy of the array and return that. Currently, your `char[] charArray` gets *modified* inside the method, and is also returned. I would suggest making the method `public static void sortCharArray(char[] charArray)`